# Visual Studio C++ intellisense wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, include, intellisense

So I have created a solution with three projects within it. Each relies on the other and complies without an issue. However, within one of the static libraries intellisense is flagging an include.

```
Cannot open source file "mmm.h"
```

This file is a local include, within the same folder and right next to it in the solution explorer.

Again everything still compiles and functions correctly without an issue... So it is working and intellisense is wrong??? Either way I'd like it to go away. Any help is appreciated, if you would like more information, please ask.